# C# WP8 format text for reminder.content

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, string-formatting, reminders

I would like to format the content text of a reminder. I'm trying to make the navigation element of a reminder more intuitive. There are buttons for snooze and dismiss, but clicking the text to navigate wasn't apparent to me. So far all I have for customization is \r\n for spacing in the text. I tried basic html, but no luck with that. Searches came up empty.

Is there any way to format this text further? underline, bold, color, center?

Is there an object with more customization than a reminder that can navigate into the app, on tap, at a scheduled time?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.